# F# with OpenTK example?

Tags: f#, gpu, opencl, opentk

Is anybody aware of a possibility to use C# libraries like OpenTK (http://www.opentk.com/) from F#, too? 
I'm especially interested in a Math toolkit library to give some scripts extra speed by taking advantage of the GPU from within F#.

What's a painless way to do that? :)

Comment: So you're asking whether its possible to use C# libraries from F#? Yes, it is. Any C# examples will translate line-for-line in F#, will likely need a little cleanup to make imperative code more idiomatic.

Comment: Oh, in that case that would have been my answer to accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Juliet mentions, you can use any .NET library from F#. Talking about OpenTK specifically, there is some material written by Laurent Le Brun (however, all of them are about graphics and not math):

- An introductory article: [F# + OpenGL: a cross-platform sample](http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2010/06/23/57-fsharp-opengl-a-cross-platform-sample)
- More examples are in the `samples/opengl` directory in the [F# cross platform project](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex

It's probably not *exactly* the same thing as you're looking for, but it should help (e.g. if there are some tricky things that need to be done when using OpenTK from F#)